# php echo time as default

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, default

I am creating a php code which i am trying to echo a default value.

What should i be using else, elseif or can i give it a default value of the server date.

This is part of the code im working on at the moment.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
echo "<p>".date("l jS F Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, ($_POST["year"])))."</p>";
    } 
}   
?>
```

What i have tried:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
    echo "<p>".date("l jS F Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, ($_POST["year"])))."</p>";
    } else {
    print date("l jS F Y");
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: sorry? what are the conditions that the date should meet in order that the default value is printed/not printed?

Comment: What on earth... `for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){` ?

Comment: @Mike It appears this lady has just opened a very large can of worms and then fled the scene.

Comment: @Daisy you edited your question, but the mysterious for loop is still there! what's it `for`? And is the `else` supposed to be inside the `if` scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop is a bit strange, and I'm not 100% sure that this is what you're asking, but it looks as though you want to echo $day under some condition, otherwise the default server date.

```
<?php
$day = date("l jS F Y"); //default to server date
if (condition){ // your condition that you didn't give...
    for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){ // a for loop that only runs once?
        $day =  date("d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, date("Y")+$i)); 
    }
}
echo $day;
?>
```

The for - else construct that you have going on is incorrect in php. Are you thinking about python? Even in that case, it wouldn't have the behavior you want -- the else clause would execute every time. 
Edit - I had an incorrect assumption that for-else was supported in PHP

I included your loop because I assumed you just wrote throwaway code to explain your problem. Obviously, repeatedly setting the date will be useless, and a for loop that only runs once is very useless!

Comment: Actually, it's technically incorrect to do a `for-else` loop: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /var/www/test.php on line 4`

Comment: loading the page displays the default to server date when i submit (post) my code shows a new date, the problem is i cant get it to go back to default date even refreshing the page.

Comment: @DaisyOopsy I'm not completely sure what your goal is; could you edit your question to reflect exactly what you're trying to do and exactly what seems to be going wrong?

Comment: you have answered my question by the looks of it, im just trying to work out how to prevent "repeat any action" on refresh.

Comment: @DaisyOopsy I would recommend posting a new question asking about that -- I'm actually not sure how you would do that, and your question's title doesn't attract someone who would be.

Comment: Sorry you answered my question "php echo time as default" thank you that works, this is just another problem now after your fix.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34878/discussion-between-daisy-oopsy-and-rogaos)